# Standard library packages still importable despite modifying sys.path

Tags: python

Suppose I want to make packages from standard library non-importable. So "datetime", "collections", and the like should not be importable when running `import datetime`.

I don't have a use case for this, but achieving this will help me understand how Python is resolving packages.

I have tried doing this:

```
import sys
sys.path = []
sys.prefix = ''
sys.exec_prefix = ''
```

But despite this, when I run `import datetime`, the package is found (which resides in /usr/lib/python3.6 directory on Ubuntu).

I also tried starting Python with `python3.6 -S -s` to avoid automatic loading of site.py, but also this did not help.

My guess is that the Ubuntu-shipped Python interpreter has the path `/usr/lib/pythonX.Y` hard-coded, but I was not able to confirm this through extensive internet searching.

So how does Python know that it should look in `/usr/lib/pythonX.Y/` directory?

Comment: Have you tried looking at `sys.modules` to see if `datetime` has already been loaded before your `import` statement?

Comment: @KyleWillmon Yes it is in there. But how do I prevent `datetime` (or any other package in there) from being loaded in the first place?

Comment: To prevent it from being loaded in the first place, you have to know what is loading it. In my Ubuntu 18.04 environment with Python 3.6, the `datetime` module is not loaded on startup.

Comment: @KyleWillmon Are you sure? This means you should get an error when you do `import datetime` because the module has not been loaded.

Comment: Yep. I get an error when I run `import datetime` after running your code.